# Failed to connect to XX.XX.XXX.XX port 9200: Connection refused on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, networking, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I've installed Elasticsearch on an EC2 Ubuntu 14 server.

I can see it's running:

```
elastic@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx:~$ curl -get localhost:9200
{
  "name" : "ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "V6axWUV9SoqABC8sX62XMQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.0.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "e4efcb5",
    "build_date" : "2019-04-29T12:57:03.145736Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.0.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.7.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I've added it to the security group:

[image]

But I can't connect from remote:

```
C:\>curl -get http://XX.XX.XXX.XX:9200/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to XX.XX.XXX.XX port 9200: Connection refused
```

netstat -nlp |grep 9200:

```
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9200          :::*                    LISTEN      29467/java   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9200                :::*                    LISTEN      29467/java
```

This is the content of elasticsearch.yml after removing all comments:

```
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
```

Comment: please run this command "netstat -nlp |grep 9200" and share the output

Comment: and please share elasticsearch.yml file

Comment: this error comes from server not curl command. are you sure that the listening port is 9200? try: netstat -ln | grep 9200 and see the status of that port.

Comment: @hamidbayat I've added the result from netstat -nlp |grep 9200

Comment: I've updated my question, included the result from netstat -nlp |grep 9200

Comment: @hamidbayat and also elasticsearch.yml

Comment: @Alon ,can you add http port also in your AWS security group?

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal if I choose HTTP rathar than TCP then it automatically chooses port 80 and doesn't let me change it.

Comment: there is no need to uncomment http.port. it is set to 9200 by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

First thing I had to configure was `network.host`, but very important to notice that it didn't work with the IP I was trying to connect to from the client, because this is the EC2 public IP. I had to use the EC2 private IP.

But then I kept getting the same error, and I've found out that the cluster coordination algorithm has changed in Elasticsearch 7.0 and in order to be safe it requires some specific configuration. Elastic relax that requirement (that is, they run in a less-safe mode) when one binds to localhost only, but if/when one changes `network.host` they enforce that he configures the cluster safely.

So, since I use a single node cluster, I had to add the following setting to the Discovery section in elasticsearch.yml:

```
discovery.type: single-node
```

Comment: it would be great also if you can link the official ES docs, which has details of changed custer co-oridination algo and where they suggest `discovery.type: single-node`

Answer (score 0):

please add the following line in elasticsearch.yml and restart elasticsearch service:

```
network.host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is your elasticsearch server's IP address

Comment: Now I cannot connect both from remote and from the same machine. I've also tried to uncomment the http.port setting.

Comment: @Alon The problem has not been solved yet? can you send netstat -nlp |grep 9200 after changing the setting and restarting the service?

Comment: it seems that AWS does not allow to use IP as network.host. please try this and let me know if it is work: network.host: \_ec2\_